# How to use Cordova's splash screen API

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have built an iOS app and set the splash (loading) screens in my .plist file, but when I load the app it still shows Cordova's default loading image (see image below).

I see there is an API for this [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen) but I am unsure how to use it or if this is even what I am after.

I am running Cordova 2.7 (and JQuery mobile if that matters).

Would anyone know how to ammend this?

[image]

Comment: have you used navigator.splashscreen.hide() and did not worked as expected?

Comment: @VladStirbu Thats what I do not understand. I have tried implementing the example to no avail. I dont understand how it works anyway since the boot image isnt HTML/Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you replaced the images with your own in the Resources/Splash folder in the app ?

(Do so in finder rather then xcode!) 
Also remember to 'Clean' your build as xcode has a habit of storing that type of thing.